# Is there a limit to how many cells I can assign to an array?

Tags: vba

I am trying to assign all the values from a column to an array using VBA.

```
Dim all_datapoints() As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    'get number of datapoints in the desired column
    n = .Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Row

    'assign column values to array
    all_datapoints = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(n, 4)))

End With
```

The value of n is about 240,000 but the array all_datapoints() only contains 42,783 datapoints. I looked over my datasheet and there are no N/A, Error, or missing values in this column (should just be a column of strings). I am not sure why it refuses to get the rest of the data.

Even if I include `ReDim all_act_molecules(1 to n)` before assigning the range, it limits to only grab the first 42,783 values. Help!

Comment: There's  a limit to `Transpose`. Btw, it's probably better to use a 2D array: `all_datapoints = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(n, 4)).Value`.

Comment: Amazing! thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx